# sql query joining three tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have to select `category name,description,id` from the `tbl_ticket_categories` from that selected `id` I have to find the `user_id` from the `tbl_ticket_repliers` and from that `user_id` I have to find the `username` from the `tbl_users`.

Finally selected attributes should be `category_name, description and username` . 
What I am doing my view is :-

```
    function editCategory($site_referers_id) {
        $this->db->select('tbl_ticket_categories.category_name,tbl_ticket_categories.description,tbl_users.username,tbl_ticket_repliers.user_id');
        $this->db->where('site_referers_id',$site_referers_id);
        $this->db->join('tbl_ticket_repliers','tbl_ticket_repliers.category_id = tbl_ticket_categories.id');
        $this->db->join('tbl_users','tbl_users.id = tbl_ticket_repliers.user_id');
        return $this->db->get('tbl_ticket_categories');
    }
```

In my view, when I am doing `<?php var_dump($categories); ?>`
it showing :-

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)[32]
  public 'conn_id' => resource(43, mysql link persistent)
  public 'result_id' => resource(81, mysql result)
  public 'result_array' => 
    array
      empty
  public 'result_object' => 
    array
      empty
  public 'custom_result_object' => 
    array
      empty
  public 'current_row' => int 0
  public 'num_rows' => int 1
  public 'row_data' => null
```

How to do this query :(

my tables are :-

`tbl_ticket_categories(id , category_name , description , site_referers_id)`

`tbl_ticket_repliers(id , user_id , category_id , site_referer_id)`

`tbl_users(id , role_id , username , password )`

**SOLVED**

Comment: Could you add the table structure perhaps? Might be easier to fully understand your question then.

Comment: @ArnoMoonen i have added my table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is correct query, the problem was I wrote result_array instead of result_array() and next time I deleted whole sentence and used var_dump().

sorry

Answer (score 2):

```
function editCategory($site_referers_id) {
        $this->db->select('tbl_ticket_categories.category_name,tbl_ticket_categories.description,tbl_users.username,tbl_ticket_repliers.user_id');
        $this->db->where('site_referers_id',$site_referers_id);
        $this->db->join('tbl_ticket_repliers','tbl_ticket_repliers.category_id = tbl_ticket_categories.id');
        $this->db->join('tbl_users','tbl_users.id = tbl_ticket_repliers.user_id');
        return $this->db->get('tbl_ticket_categories')->result_array();
    }
```

add `result_array()` above query and `print_r() instead of var_dump` u see the result